# Setting user's SimpleDisplayName via EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I'm trying to update *Simple Display Name* property of a user using Exchange EWS Managed APIs, but I'm not sure either about which is the correct object/class to interact to update users' attributes.

What I have tried is retrieving all [UserSettingsName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.autodiscover.usersettingname(v=exchg.80).aspx), with same code used and available in this example [Exchange 2013: Get user settings with Autodiscover](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-Get-user-7e22c86e), but the key/value I'm looking for isn't there.

Using PowerShell `Get-User` and `Set-User` cmdlets the value can be correctly read and set, as explained in this article [Using the SimpleDisplayName attribute for Exchange and Exchange Online in Office 365 with PowerShell](https://thomasverwer.com/2016/03/15/using-the-simpledisplayname-attribute-for-exchange-and-exchange-online-in-office-365-with-powershell/)

`$user = Get-User admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
Set-User $user.Identity -SimpleDisplayName "My Display Name"`

But I would like to be able to read/write the value of this property via EWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set or get that property via EWS as its not meant to be user set-able property (eg only admins should be able to change this and that must be done via the Admin interface eg EMS or EAC).

Comment: Thanks for your answer